# USB 3G dongle Internet keeps failing on a laptop with Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, usb, modem, troubleshooting, mobile

I use a 3G dongle for Internet in my summerhouse. It has worked fine all summer, but since yesterday it has been losing connection, or something and I have to unplug it and insert it again for the Internet to come back on. This is very frustrating.

The device is a USB Huawei 3G dongle with SIM-card.

How do I troubleshoot such a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to find out if the cause appeared on the *mobile network operator side*, or on *the client side* (PC with modem), or possibly it's from *environmental conditions*.

The **network** changes include:

- vertical aerial adjustment: then you get less radio power in favour of location in front and behind you in relation to the base station aerial
- horizontal aerial adjustment: places on your side get more power at your cost
- network hardware changes: the aerials get swapped for some reasons or the BTSs, and some coverage changes may creep in
- network optimisation algorithm changes: this is complex and goes hand in hand with the next one,
- network load increase

Regarding the last two, the network is programmed to connect your modem in certain technologies (2G or GSM, 3G, 4G). The way it does it depends on:

- the technologies your modem can operate in
- the signal strength for different aerials, which your modem reports to the network all the time
- current load in different technologies and network availability, eg. there's only a certain number of users that can be actively using a single GSM channel (a single frequency range)

The **PC and modem** side changes include:

- driver and software updates
- driver and software configuration and settings changes
- physical device condition changes:

  - modems sometimes break
  - if you use an aerial, check the cable and the connector
- OS updates

The **environment** part includes:

- weather and astronomic conditions
- obstructions in the radio line of sight (building works, for example)
- interference from home appliances and nearby industrial and telecommunication works

---

**The investigation** is complex, with many heuristics, so this section is rather chaotic. But the investigation can begin with checking the network condition as seen on the PC:

- *What's the current network technology?* The fact that the modem has *3G* in its name doesn't mean it will use only 3G. Most likely 3G is its top limit, while it can use GSM as well, and so it reports to the network. Modems can be locked in technologies, I'll describe this later.
- *What's the current signal strength?* It may be represented with ascending stairs or in numbers by a percentage or dBm (-80 dBm is excellent, -100 dBm is good, -115 is poor).

You need to observe how the above two behave over time.

- If you have an *aerial*, check it, including its assembly, the connector and cabling, and *its location*. If you don't, getting it is one of the basic fixes. The modem should have an aerial connector somewhere on the casing. If no external aerial is present, it uses its internal aerial. Thus take into consideration where the modem itself is placed. You can use *a USB extension* and hang it somewhere high and better exposed to the network aerial (no metal or concrete obstructions in the line of sight, etc). *Have you moved the aerial or the modem in the meantime?* *Have you changed the USB extension?*
- If you have *another OS* at hand, you can compare how the modem works with it. Are the signal strength and technology the same? Do you experience similar problems?
- You can *check the network with another device* like a phone. But make sure what you're checking. Different operators have different infrastructure. You will be 100% sure when you test with the SIM card you use in your modem.
- If the coverage is bad, to test if the PC plus modem configuration is fine, *go to a good coverage area*. This can help you rule out a large branch of possibilities in the troubleshooting tree.
- Test the behaviour when *locking to certain technologies*. You can tell the modem to report to the network that it only knows a certain set of the technologies it is able to operate in. (Let's make the technical side of how to do this in Linux another question.) The idea is to avoid being pushed around by the network, to weigh the anchor. Completely unlocked, the modem is prone to constant movement effecting from the network unstableness. Either trying to make itself comfortable and trying to make the modem the most comfortable it can be, the network tells it to now jump to GSM from this site (aerial, BTS), now to 3G from this one, and sometimes it doesn't help. Quite the opposite, the modem goes nearly useless. But when it's not interested in its own welfare, so to say, it can get a better deal. For example, locking to 3G in bad radio conditions can bring benefit. Sometimes the network is very poor, but when it's ok, it's ok, and 3G is so much faster than EDGE (2G, GSM), that overall throughput statistics are far higher. The radio conditions fluctuate all the time, sometimes dramatically, sometimes prosaically.
- Finally, you can call the network operator and ask them if they've introduced any changes in your location. They may be helpful. Or not.

---

**Fixes** include:

- changing the physical location of the modem or its external aerial
- getting a new USB cable
- getting an aerial (2 aerials for LTE)
- locking the modem into a technology
- contacting the network operator and getting a fix from them
- changing the network operator
- reversing software and driver updates
- getting a new modem

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first try your computer in another place, preferably closer to the cellphone base station, and see if the reception is better from there. That should give you an indication whether the device malfunctions or not. (Don't get directly beneath the providers antenna's, my experience is that you can get bad reception there).

Obstruction of the signal can happen in the same way that a wireless router can be obstructed. Assuming your summerhouse is not covered by many base stations you could try and find out if something happened 'on route' between the base station and your device. I have seen simple things as someone standing close to your computer to the filling up of an in-house pool affect reception.

If you test reception quality with a cell-phone, make sure you use the same provider. Also be aware that a phone might not indicate 3G reception quality, but GSM quality instead (or even connect to a closer base station only supporting GSM (2G)).